# Saving files when app loads first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have an `angular2` app connected with a node server. What I am trying to accomplish is following: I have an API that gives me an array of URLs of images, and every time an app starts, I want it to download all the images from that array on local storage where the app was started. (ex. when I run the app from a laptop, all images will be downloaded to the laptop)

I can do this in node using `fs`, but that downloads an image to server, instead of to local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get access to the "Window" object in your Angular 2 code and call localStorage.setItem(...) on that instance.

You can get the window like anything else in Angular 2: the DI should provide an instance for you in the constructor.